# Special arrays merge or reshape (like pushing two combs together)

Tags: python-3.x

I want to merge two (or more) arrays using numpy as bellow

```
a=
[[1 3]
[5 7]
[9 11]
[13 15]]
b=
[[2 4]
[6 8]
[10 12]
[14 16]]
```

into

```
Result=
[[1 2]
[3 4]
[5 6]
[7 8]
[9 10]
[11 12]
[13 14]
[15 16]]
```

I honesty searched whole net and tested all numpy family, I will be thankful if you give me a clue.

Comment: Why does numpy.reshape not work? Can you provide code as to what your array looks like?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: reshape doesnt work. I tested it in any way you can imagine.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code and point out where it does not work? Do you have a python list of numpy arrays?

Comment: I test and prepare a reply

Comment: I just tested and a python list of numpy arrays would have worked too. That question just now from me was not relevant.

Comment: my question is wrong i edit it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to interweave the elements from the two arrays regardless of the nesting. Then you can ravel them first and then zip:

```
a=[[1, 3],[5, 7], [9, 11], [13, 15]]
b=[[2, 4],[6, 8],[10, 12],[14, 16]]

a_1d = np.ravel(a)
b_1d = np.ravel(b)

c = np.array(list(zip(a_1d,b_1d)))
print(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: This answer was intended for an older edit of the question.

---

For small arrays, you should first concatenate them, then perform the standard reshaping.

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
>>> b = [[9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
>>> a + b
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
>>> result = np.reshape(a + b, (8, -1))
>>> print(result)
[[ 1  2]
 [ 3  4]
 [ 5  6]
 [ 7  8]
 [ 9 10]
 [11 12]
 [13 14]
 [15 16]]
>>>
```

For larger ones, creating a numpy ndarrays should be more efficient. Again, concatenate first.

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])
>>> b = np.array([[9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]])
>>> result = np.reshape(np.concatenate([a, b]), (8, -1))
>>> print(result)
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 9, 10],
       [11, 12],
       [13, 14],
       [15, 16]])
```

Comment: But, apparently my big code needed this edited question to be answered. I am working on it too. May you have a look on it please, if it is possible.

Comment: Oh well, glad you got your answer!